# Socket programming, using ip addresses

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix

I have a simple tcp client server program. Client sends text, server prints it ito terminal. I need to make it so client can connect to server by ip address, no just a port (i have it on localhost now). How can I do this? Tried many things, getting errors everytime. 
Here's the client code:

```
int client(char * add)  //add is an address passed, either hostname (for ex. google.com) 
{                       //or just a normal dotted ip (1.2.3.4)
    int s, t, len;
    struct sockaddr_un remote;
    char str[100];

    if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Trying to connect...\n");

    remote.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);
    len = strlen(remote.sun_path) + sizeof(remote.sun_family);
    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, len) == -1) {
        perror("connect");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Connected.\n");
    int i=0;
    while(fgets(str, 100, stdin)) {
        if (send(s, str, strlen(str), 0) == -1) {
            perror("send");
            exit(1);
        }

    }

    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

And tere's a server:

```
int server(void)
{
    int s, s2, t, len;
    int z;
    struct sockaddr_un local, remote;
    char str[100];

    if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    local.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(local.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);
    unlink(local.sun_path);
    len = strlen(local.sun_path) + sizeof(local.sun_family);
    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&local, len) == -1) {
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (listen(s, 5) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(;;) {
        int done, n;
        t = sizeof(remote);
        if ((s2 = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *) &remote, (socklen_t *) &t)) == -1) {
            perror("accept");
            exit(1);
        }
        done = 0;
        do {
            n = recv(s2, str, 100, 0);
            if (n <= 0) {
                if (n < 0) perror("recv");
                done = 1;
            }


            if (!done) 
                printf("%s", str);
                fflush(stdout);
                sleep(1);
        } while (!done);

        close(s2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can I connect my client with that server using ip address? 
My driver funtion chooses if I want to start a server or a client, it's all in one file.
To start a server i use:

```
./main.o -l [port]
```

and to start a client I'd want to use:

```
./main.o [address] [port]
```

I don't realy know how to translate the address and then use it to connect. I mean, I've tried gethostbyname(), but then I didn't know where tu put this address because sockaddr_un has no address field to fill.

Comment: There are tens of thousands of networking tutorials all over the Internet. They should all be able to tell you how to use e.g. ***TCP*** sockets.

Comment: And don't forget that `AF_UNIX` is also known as `AF_LOCAL`. That is, it's for local communication *only*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So I guess, I'l have to use AF_INET and socaddr_in, right?

Comment: Yes that's right.